# Python Tkinter GUI interface

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a problem with GUI interface of Tkinter. The text does not print in the shell, but if `Entry` is placed in the first tk window `get()` it works... Help me?

Here is my code:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
##CONFIG FRS TK
import tkinter as tk
window = Tk()
window.geometry("600x500")
window.title("Gestione caldaie")
window.config(bg="gray")

name2=StringVar()
def enter():
    print(name2.get())

def test():
    clienti_caldaie=Tk()
    clienti_caldaie.resizable(False,False)
    clienti_caldaie.geometry("800x550")
    clienti_caldaie.title("Clienti e Caldaie")
    clienti_caldaie.config(bg = "#9999ff")

    ##DATI UTENTE
    name = Label(clienti_caldaie, text = "Nome e Cognome ", font = "bold", bg = "#9999ff").place(x = 0, y = 3)

    named = Entry(clienti_caldaie,textvariable=name2).place(x = 150, y = 4) 
    but=Button(text="Save",command=enter).place(x = 70, y = 10)

clienti = Button(text = "New", command=test).place(x = 30, y = 60)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You shouldn't create more than one instance of Tk(). If you wish to create a new dialog use [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm).

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't use more than one instance of Tk(). You should use Toplevel for new dialogs.

For example

```
import os
from tkinter import *
##CONFIG FRS TK
import tkinter as tk
window = Tk()
window.geometry("600x500")
window.title("Gestione caldaie")
window.config(bg="gray")

name2=StringVar()
def enter():
    print(name2.get())

def test():
    clienti_caldaie=Toplevel()
    clienti_caldaie.resizable(False,False)
    clienti_caldaie.geometry("800x550")
    clienti_caldaie.title("Clienti e Caldaie")
    clienti_caldaie.config(bg = "#9999ff")

    ##DATI UTENTE
    name = Label(clienti_caldaie, text = "Nome e Cognome ", font = "bold", bg = "#9999ff").place(x = 0, y = 3)

    named = Entry(clienti_caldaie,textvariable=name2).place(x = 150, y = 4) 
    but=Button(clienti_caldaie,text="Save",command=enter).place(x = 70, y = 10)

clienti = Button(text = "New", command=test).place(x = 30, y = 60)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks , but I have already solved ! I have new problem with `messagebox` in a function...   :/